# How to open a CSV,read a particular header of column and get the highest value

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I want to know How to open a CSV,read a particular header of column and get the highest value.The value should be stored in a variab

regards,
sid

Comment: To start with take a look at the documentation of 'csv' module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CSV](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)-module for reading the file. To get the highest value, you will have to read the entire file and and always remember the highest value seen so far.

Comment: i tried the following script as per ur suggestion and i get an error import csv

def main():
 col_name = "\\xyz-abc\Procz(abcd)\Digital"
 with open('C:\\read.csv', 'rb') as inf:
  reader = csv.reader(inf)
  col_index = next(reader).index(col_name)
  highest = max(rec[col_index] for rec in reader)
  print "test"
main()     i get an error ValueError: '\\\\xyz-abc\Procz(abcd)\Digital' is not in list   please help me..

Comment: @Siddharth: This is unreadable in a comment. You should create a new question, and refer to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `csv` module to parse the file.  Calling `next(reader)` for a `csv.Reader` object will yield the first line as a tuple.  You can use the `index()` method of tuples to find the index of the column name you are looking for.  Finally, using `max()` with a generator expression extracts the highest value of the column you are looking for:

```
import csv
col_name = "name"
with open("file.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    col_index = next(reader).index(col_name)
    highest = max(rec[col_index] for rec in reader)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you open csv files as `rb`?

Comment: @Jakob: Thanks, you are right.  I always forget about those pitiful Windows poeple! (I know, in Python 3.x this is needed in any case...)

Comment: :3 I get grilled for forgetting it all of the time... Its one of those "Oh... your a windows user are you? Go sit over there with the safety paper and glue"

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I got to try this out.